# Changing Texbox color

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

I m using ASP.NET. i want to change `forecolor` and size at run time using java script or any other client script.

i don't want to use server methods because it causing full post back.

What i m doing is. i m creating one simple image. on that image i m writing text whatever written in one `textbox`.

now i want to set text color and its size also at run time. currently it is hard coded.

so i m looking for changing text color and size of `textbox` at run time using any client script.

Changing in style property of `textbox` is not working. i m able to set text color but not able to access it using `TextBox1.ForeColor` property.

Help me please

Answer (score 1):

Look at generated html and write according javascript:

```
document.getElementById('txtbox').style.color = 'red';
```

And size:

```
var txtbox = document.getElementById('txtbox')
txtbox.style.width = '10px';
txtbox.style.height = '20px';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing color on client side and want to access the changed value on server side. TextBox won't remember this sort of change after a postback. You should pass the changed color to the server separately, possibly in a hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (using jQuery):

```
$("#textboxID").css('background','Red')
$("#textboxID").css('font-size','25px')
```